# Is there a elegant way to handle Either Monad in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, either, circe

I am starting up on Scala, doing a project with circe to handle JSON.

I am coming accross a lot of Either returns from functions, and I don't seem to find a elegant way to handle all of them.

For instance, for a single either, I do as in this snippet:

```
if (responseJson.isRight) {
//do something
} else {
//do something else
}
```

But what should I do when I have a lot of them in sequence, such as this example in which I just go straight for the right side and I feel I should be doing some extra validation:

```
ClassA(
       someValue,
       someValue,
       someJson.hcursor.get[Double]("jsonKey1").right.get,
       someJson.hcursor.get[Double]("jsonKey2").right.get,
       someJson.hcursor.get[Double]("jsonKey3").right.get
      )
```

How should/can I handle multiple `Either` objects (without ending up with a bunch of if-elses, or similar) when I want to get their contents if they are a `Right`, but not I am not sure they are always a `Right` ?

Comment: You almost never want to `get` things out of a `Monad`... `Monad` generally encapsulate extra properties around a `type`. For example, lets say you have a gift box which is known to contain either a mobile phone or nothing. Now, with this box in hand, you can never say that you will make a phone call but you can either be able to make a phone call or do nothing.

Comment: Not sure I understood, but i'll try to explain better using your example:
I don't want to have boxes that may or may not have phones, I want to open all boxes, get the phones if they have one inside, otherwise do something else - like abort the operation or something. 
My situation is one in which I am not able to trust that all boxes have phones, so what I am trying to understand is how can I elegantly check the boxes without a bunch of  `if-else` clauses.

Comment: Well... if you look at my answer, it does exactly that. So, you have a mystery box of `Int` and another mystery box of `String`. You can use both of these to build another mystery box of whatever you needed using the `Int` and `String` (without any usage of if-else). Once you have that, you can use a single if-else or match-case (recommended over if-else) to do handle that single mystery box.

Comment: Ah! Okay, now with this added more "plain wordy" explanation, I understood it. Thanks! I accepted your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a case class,

```
case class Demo(i: Int, s: String)
```

and two eithers,

```
val intEither: Either[Throwable, Int] = ???
val stringEither: Either[Throwable, Int] = ???
```

So... lets start with the most basic and obvious one,

```
val demoEither: Either[Throwable, Demo] = 
  intEither.flatMap(i => 
    stringEither.map(s => Demo(i, s))
  )
```

Another way is to do the same as above is to use for-comprehensions,

```
val demoEither: Either[Throwable, Demo] = 
  for {
    i <- intEither 
    s <- stringEither
  } yield Demo(i, s)
```

But, `monads` are sequential, which means that if the first `Either` is a `Left` then you will not even look at the second `Either` and just get a `Left`. This is mostly undesirable for validations because you don't want to loose the validation information of all components, so what you actually want is an `Applicative`.

And `Either` is not an `Applicative`, you will have to use `cats` or `scalaz` or implement your own applicative for this.

cats provides the `Validated` applicative for this express purpose which lets you validate and keep all error information of the validated components.

```
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

val intValidated: ValidatedNec[Throwable, Int] = 
  intEither.toValidatedNec

val stringValidated: ValidatedNec[Throwable, String] =
  stringEither.toValidatedNec

val demoValidated: ValidatedNec[Throwable, Demo] = 
  (intValidated, stringValidated).mapN(Demo)

val demoEither: Either[List[Throwable], Demo] = 
  demoValidated.leftMap(errorNec => errorNec.toList)
```

Or, if you are doing this just once and don't want to depend on `cats`, you can just use pattern-matching which is very versatile

```
val demoEither: Either[List[Throwable], Demo] = 
  (intEither, stringEither) match {
    case (Right(i), Right(s)) => Right(Demo(i, s))
    case (Left(ti), Left(ts)) => Left(List(ti, ts))
    case (Left(ti), _) => Left(List(ti))
    case (_, Left(ts)) => Left(List(ts))
  }
```

Comment: **Either** IS an `Applicative`, every `Monad` is an `Applicative`. The problem is than once you are also a `Monad` you are forced to be sequential. **Validated** is just an `Applicative` but not a `Monad` which allows it to do not be sequential.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I should have been more clear with my statement...  Yes, the `Either` construct itself qualifies is a `monad` and hence is also an `applicative` but the `Either` implementation in Scala standard library is not an `applicative`.

Comment: The implementation of **Either** in the standard library satisfies the laws of an `Applicative`, you only need to provide `pure` & `ap`. The former is trivial and the last can _(**has to**)_ be implemented for any type that is also a `Monad` using `flatMap`. And all methods like `mapN` are implemented in terms of `ap`. And that is where the problem resides. `mapN` doesn't guarantee sequential evaluation so it could be sequential or not. However if the underlying type also forms a `Monad` then it has to be sequential _(because at the end everything is implemented in terms of `flatMap`)_.

Comment: Well... I feel we both are saying same things with different and in-accurate words (probably just to avoid the whole trouble of writing it down and also infeasibility of writing it down in simple and short words). You are trying to approach this purely from the perspective of corresponding type-class hierarchy. And I am mixing both the implementations and definitions category theory. Both of which are really flawed approaches.

Comment: And, as I said the concept of `Either` qualifies both as an `applicative` and `monad`. Its just that we do not choose to provide the more versatile `applicative` type-class for `Either` (even with cats) because, doing so might allow (deliberately or mistakenly) user to break the `monad laws` which are a bit more stricter than what required for an `applicative laws` (and unwanted confusion and complexity). And that is the big difference from theoretical definitions because such problems are wholly avoidable when talking about these in theoretical context.

Comment: I did not understand this answer. 
Maybe if I rephrase the question... I will edit it.

Comment: What part did you not understand ? If it is about `monads` and `applicative` then just treat that as extra but not necessary info for you (at this point of learning).

Answer (score 2):

> How should/can I handle multiple `Either` objects (without ending up with a bunch of if-elses, or similar) when I want to get their contents if they are a `Right`, but not I am not sure they are always a `Right`?

So you have some `Either` instances, all with the same type signature.

```
val ea :Either[Throwable,String] = Right("good")
val eb :Either[Throwable,String] = Left(new Error("bad"))
val ec :Either[Throwable,String] = Right("enough")
```

And you want all the `Right` values, ignoring any `Left` values.

```
List(ea, eb, ec).collect{case Right(x) => x}
//res0: List[String] = List(good, enough)
```

You don't know which `Either` contains which `String` but I think that's what you asked for.